# Como lidar com arrays com numero de indices diferentes no mesmo loop

Tags: php, array, loop

tenho um script que faz um cadastramento

funciona assim: numa tabela dinamica, cada linha tem um input que é do tipo checkbox e ele carrega uma id e outro input é tipo number e carrega um valor qualquer

dai ocorre que $_POST fica com arrays com numeros distintos de indices. por ex, se nessa tabela eu marcar somente a ultima checkbox e colocar um valor no ultimo input number, o array do checkbox terá um valor true para seu indice 0, ao mesmo tempo que o valor que eu coloquei no input number estará em outro indice, o que significa que o loop nao vai pegar o valor number correto..

```
foreach($fator as $k => $v){
        try{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . EMP_MODALIDADES . " (eid,mid,fator) VALUES (:eid,:mid,:fator)";
            $insert = $link->prepare($sql);
            $insert->bindValue(':eid',$eid);
            $insert->bindValue(':mid',$v);
            $insert->bindValue(':fator',$fator[$k]);
            $insert->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $erro){
            die('INSERT error: '.$erro->getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

se alguém tiver essa dúvida, eu consegui resolver o problema usando um input hidden junto com o input number.. daí, repliquei as ids que eram 'perdidas' nos arrays menores (caso nao marcasse todos os checkboxes) e pude fazer as inserções adequadamente